# how to save variable number of arguments of same type and same name in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

A form is submitted in rails which have variable number of invoiced items, with a boolean value as true or false.How can I get all these values and save them in the database in the respective fields:
Request parameters are as:

```
        <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cCQjRuaHnsIkCaffZfi6t3err4YPxrEWXSXNKy4gFmDUOtWt+T4JALddxkJWo/7giXD3dNXlvJz9tJ0EYDKKjQ==",
     "invoiced_186"=>"1", "invoiced_187"=>"1", "invoiced_188"=>"1",
     "invoiced_189"=>"1", "invoiced_190"=>"1",
 "commit"=>"save", "controller"=>"cader/caders", "action"=>"add_invoiced_items", "id"=>"63813"} permitted: false>
```

Form templated is as:

```
          <%= form_with url: cader_add_invoiced_items_path(@job_checkout.id), local: true do |f| %>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
          <th>Item #</th>
          <th>File</th>
          <th>Service</th>
          <th>Price $USD</th>
          <th>Invoice</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <% @done_job.each do |done_job| %>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <%= f.check_box :"invoiced_#{done_job.id}" %>
                <label>
                  <%= done_job.id %>
                </label>
              </td>
              <td><%= done_job.file_name %></td>
              <td><%= done_job.service %></td>
              <td>$<%= done_job.amount %></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <%= f.submit 'save' %>
```

How to manage them in server side because the field inoice_x is variable in number.

Comment: How about looping through params? For ex: `params.each {|k,v| do_something if k.to_s.include?("invoiced_")}`

Comment: @AkshayGoya , yes we could do it in this way, I was thinking if there is another way round to the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can name your checkboxes like this

```
<checkbox name="invoiced[]" value="187">
```

You should receive an array of values checked. (Sorry, I can't test it ATM)

```
[187, 188]
```

Or do this

```
<checkbox name="invoiced[187]" >
```

Then, I believe you'd receive a hash

```
{187 = 1, 188 = 1}
```

Comment: yes, I can create this in array like using pure html , but is there way to do it using rails way by using rails tags.